# Github push error

Tags: git, github

I am getting the following errors when I try to push to my github repo:

```
error: src refspec BRANCH does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/
```

I have gone through numerous SO answers but couldn't find a solution.

```
git show-ref
```

doesn't show anything. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the command you used for pushing?

Comment: `git push origin master`. I also tried `git push -u origin master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to clone your GitHub repo and report your commits from your previous local repo

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
cd <repo>
git remote add firstrepo ../firstrepo
git fetch firstrepo
git branch -avv
git checkout -b fmaster firstrepo/master 
git rebase master
git checkout master
git push
```

But if you don't want to re-import your local repo in a new clone, check your remote and branches:

```
git remote -v
git branch -avv
```

You `git config --local -l` should look like:

```
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Since `git branch -avv` shows nothing, **make sure you have added and committed first something, before attempting any `git push`**:

```
git config user.name <GitHub account Name>
git config user.email <GitHub account email>
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: When I tried `git push -u origin --all` it said `No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
`

Comment: @RaviTej310 Hence my suggestion to check the output of `git remote -v` and `git branch -avv`. We'll know more then.

Comment: `git remote -v` output: `origin https://github.com/RaviTej310/Andrew_Ng_Machine_Learning.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/RaviTej310/Andrew_Ng_Machine_Learning.git (push)
` and `git branch -avv ` shows nothing

Comment: `git config --local -l` shows `core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/RaviTej310/Andrew_Ng_Machine_Learning.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
`

Comment: @RaviTej310 OK, I have added a process at the end of my answer.

Comment: Some process of compressing and writing objects is happening. I'll let you know once it's done. Do I need to do this every time I create a new repo and try to push code? I never had this problem on Windows but in ubuntu, I do.

Comment: @RaviTej310 make sure your repo does not include too many object/files. Creating a repo under / would be a bad idea, as a git add would add all the content of / (and subfolders). Try with a small repo first. Any push will push commits. If you don't add and create commits, you cannot push.